# aggregate function calls may not be nested postgres error

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW gender_log_counts AS
 SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, 
     CASE 
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) > 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f>18'
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) > 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm>18'
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) <= 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f<18'
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) <= 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm<18' 
 END AS gender_age_category,
 mlc.facility_id,
 COALESCE(SUM(mlc.count),0) AS total,
 COALESCE(SUM(mlc.general), 0) AS general,
 COALESCE(SUM(mlc.course), 0) AS course,
 COALESCE(SUM(mlc.club), 0) AS club 
FROM
 members m
LEFT JOIN
 member_log_counts mlc ON mlc.tc_no = m.tc_no
GROUP BY
 gender_age_category,
 mlc.facility_id;
```

I want to create a view which takes a table and another view which is called `member_log_counts`. `mlc.count`, `mlc.general`, `mlc.course`, `mlc.club` are all generated from sums in the `member_log_counts`. I think because the are sums and here I try to calculate another sum and they are probably creating this error:`aggregate function calls may not be nested`.
How can I solve this? Why it counts as if I am doing 2 sums at the same time? I did the sum in the previous view.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of long CASE WHEN is better something like:
```
substr(m.gender, 1, 1) || CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) > 18 THEN '>18' ELSE '<18' END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE VIEW gender_log_counts AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) > 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f>18'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) > 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm>18'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) <= 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f<18'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) <= 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm<18' 
    END AS gender_age_category,
    mlc.facility_id,
    COALESCE(mlc.total, 0) AS total,
    COALESCE(mlc.general, 0) AS general,
    COALESCE(mlc.course, 0) AS course,
    COALESCE(mlc.club, 0) AS club 
FROM
    members m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tc_no,
        facility_id,
        SUM(count) AS total,
        SUM(general) AS general,
        SUM(course) AS course,
        SUM(club) AS club
    FROM member_log_counts
    GROUP BY tc_no, facility_id
) mlc ON mlc.tc_no = m.tc_no;
```

try it

Comment: Please add some explanation, why you think this solves the problem.